# How to detect a user clicked on an internal or external link

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know if users clicked on an internal or external link to alert them.
I have many internal and external links on my site.

My internal links are like this:

```
<a href="about.php">about</a>
<a href="tools/draw.php">draw graph</a>
```

I need to alert only when external links are clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I've included two methods here: One method uses jQuery, and the other doesn't use jQuery. Skip down to the bold heading if you don't want to use jQuery)

One way you could do this is by adding a class to each external link, and then attaching an event handler to everything in that class which raises an alert when you click the link. That's tedious, though, as you have to add the class to *every* external link, and it won't for user generated content.

What you can do is use jQuery, along with the CSS selector `a[href^="http"]`, to select all the external links, and then attach an event handler that raises your alert when they're clicked:

```
$('a[href^="http"]').click(function() {
    alert();
});
```

`a[href^="http"]` means "an `a` tag which has a link, and that link has to start with 'http'." So here we select all the elements which start with `http` - that is, every external link - and then set it so that when you click on them, an alert pops up.

**Non-jQuery method**

If you want to do this without jQuery, you'll want to use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"]')` and bind the click event of each element in the array that that function returns. That looks something like this:

```
var externalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="http"]');
for (var i = externalLinks.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    externalLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() { alert(); }, false);
}
```

Comment: http:// doesnt mean that you're moving out of current website. Systems like WordPress uses permalinks for every internal page that include http.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this from scratch on my own site so I'll just copy + paste it here for you.  It came from inside one of my objects so if I left some `this` keywords you can remove them.

```
function leaving() {
    var links = document.anchors || document.links || document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if ((links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('http') === 0 && links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('fleeceitout') < 0) && (links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('/') !== 0 && links[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('#') !== 0) && links[i].className.indexOf('colorbox') < 0) {
            addEvent(links[i], 'click', this.action);
        }
    }
}

function action(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        link = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement;
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        window.location.href = link.href;
        return;
    }
    var leave = confirm("You are now leaving the _______ website.  If you want to stay, click cancel.");
    if (leave) {
        window.location.href = link.href;
        return;
    } else {
        return leave;
    }
}
var addEvent = function (element, myEvent, fnc) {
    return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
};
```

Replace instances of 'fleeceitout' with your sites domain name (microsoft.com, etc) and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways are with jQuery, using a special class for external links, or by checking for "http://" in the URL.

Like this, if using a special class:

```
$("a.external").on("click", function() {
    //de Do something special here, before going to the link.
    //de URL is: $(this).attr("href")
});
```

And then in HTML:

```
<a href="http://external.link" class='external'>external link</a>
```

Or, you can check for `http://` in the URL! Then you don't need a special class.

```
$('a[href=^"http://"]').on("click", function() {
    //de Do something special here, before going to the link.
    //de URL is: $(this).attr("href")
});
```

**Cite:** My original method of testing for "http://" was a bit slower, actually doing an `indexOf` test on `.attr("href")` so I used @Matthew's selector choice instead. Forgot about the caret route! Props to @Matthew on that, and for the non-jQuery alternative.

Comment: A down vote? I didn't include a non-jQuery option, true... but really?

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted, but I believe that I suggested the selector choice and a non-jQuery method (not Deryck as you have cited). Edit: Kudos! :D

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed my citation. Copy & paste casualty there.

Comment: And thanks for clarifying it wasn't you. It actually did matter to me because I did forget the selector route, which is truly better than what I had, but I did have "a" way in place. I liked your answer and didn't intend to plagiarize it at all, so I cited you on the modification to mine. I think the downvoter was my cat. She suspiciously returned to sit on my keyboard after a trip to the litter box. I think she may have procured a computer to find new ways to terrorize the lab.

Yeah, it was the cat. Only she could be that cold.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var returnType= true;
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( link.indexOf('http') >= 0 ) { 
            returnType=confirm('You are browsing to an external link.');
        }
        return returnType;
    });
 });`
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fire if I had a link like `/foo/http/bar/baz.html`? That's not an external link

Comment: That's not what you have in your answer, though.